# What are the minimum requirements of a WMI class?

Tags: wmi

I was implementing a query to the WMI class "Win32_OperatingSystem" namespace with "root\CIMV2"

I tested my code in Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows XP SP3 and everyone worked well.

However in the documentation page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx says "Minimum supported client" can only be called from a Windows Vista or later.

Why it operated in Windows XP? what are the real minimum requirements?

Comment: [Not an official resource](http://www.scriptinternals.com/new/us/Support/Internal/WMI_Win32_OperatingSystem.htm) but it says this class works in all the windows platforms. It works on my xp as well ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the information provided by @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like, and looking documentation msdn, I have come to the conclusion that the WMI classes in general, change according to the version of Windows, then the version minimal described in the official website of the msdn establese minimum supported the common class.